# Ruby Grape Api multiple routes with single method

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape, grape-api

I want to accept multiple routes in a single method.

```
resource :mypath do
  helpers do
    def mymethod
      super_duper_stuff
    end
  end

  post do
    something_else
  end

  get do
    mymethod
  end

  resource :subpath
    post do
      mymethod
    end
  end
end
```

Is there any way to combine a GET to /mypath and a POST to /mypath/subpath so I can put the code into the route method and not in the helpers section?  Something like this:

```
resource :mypath do
  post do
    something_else
  end

  get, route(['POST'], "subpath") do
    super_duper_stuff
  end
end
```

Comment: The other solution won't work for my situation, I want the subpath to accept a post and do the same method as a get to the base path.  A post to the base path does a completely different method.  The solution you marked as dupe will not work for my request.